# Does VS2022 need azure to use model builder for image recognition

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, ml.net-model-builder

I would like to use model builder to do image recognition, I followed this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/object-detection-model-builder#prerequisites
to do it in VS2019 but azure cost money would like to free way to do some image recognition. Can anyone tell me is VS2022 is there a free way and if so is there a tutorial

Thanks

Comment: "*Can anyone tell me is VS2022 is there a free way and if so is there a tutorial*" Questions seeking product recommendations and links to off-site resources are explicitly off-topic here per the scope of the site defined in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Not looking for product recommendations, Looking for a tutorial

Comment: "*Looking for a tutorial*" As I mentioned, questions seeking links to off-site resources are explicitly off-topic here per the scope of the site defined in the [help/on-topic]. Please review it.